# How can i control the numbers in a number textbox <input type="number"/> according the incremental and decremental changes done in another textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

[What i need is when the room quantity is set to 1, the adult max range be 3 and min range be 1. And when room quantity is set to 2, the adult max range be 6 and min range be 1. Can someone plz help me with javascript or jquery that is needed to solve this problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oT8r2.png)

Comment: What code have you written so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some functionality of this example. It is not a polished solution, it's just the example of how you can manipulate `max` property of `input` element.

```js
$("#roomsInput").change(function() {
 var maxAdults;
  var roomsSelected = $(this).val();
  if (roomsSelected == 1) {
   maxAdults = 3;
  } else if (roomsSelected == 2) {
   maxAdults = 6;
  } else {
   maxAdults = 10;
  }
  var adultsInput = $("#adultsInput");
  if (adultsInput.val() > maxAdults) {
   adultsInput.val(maxAdults);
  }
  adultsInput.prop("max", maxAdults);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <label>Rooms</label>
  <input type="number" id="roomsInput" min="1" max="3">
</div>
<div>
  <label>Adults</label>
  <input type="number" id="adultsInput" min="0" max="10">
</div>
<div>
  <label>Kids</label>
  <input type="number" id="kidsInput" min="0" max="10">
</div>
```

Comment: thankyou soo much for replying!!

Comment: Does it answer your question?

Comment: i tried it and it worked !! hurray